# Finding blank cells in a specific row with php/mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting at making a site that has a polling section in it. The users need to be able to take previous polls if they have not voted in them yet. So for each poll they take, it adds a note into the cell.

The table looks something like this:

```
userid   | poll1  | poll2  | poll3 | poll4  /
---------+--------+--------+-------+--------/
001      |   Y    |    Y   |       |        /
---------+--------+--------+-------+--------/
002      |   Y    |        |   Y   |        /
--------------------------------------------/
```

So now, the code would have to select poll 3 and 4 for user 001, and present that to the user on the page. I have been trying a couple different approaches to this but can't seem to find the right code.

I have looked for something for help online and haven't found anything that addresses this issue.

Comment: That doesn't scale very well, you'd be better off having a separate table connecting a user to a poll.

Comment: That table would only support N polls, where N is the number of columns. What about making a table "Polls", and then a relational table "UserPolls". The last table would have three columns "user_id", "poll_id" and a boolean "taken". The you could just find all poll_ids for a given user where "taken" is false.

Comment: set columns default value to NULL and filter query according to that

Answer (score 0):

Users

```
id | name
---+-------
 1 | tyrion
 2 | cersei
```

Polls

```
id | name
---+-------
 1 | first poll
 2 | second poll
```

UserPolls

```
user_id | poll_id
--------+-------
    1   |   1
    1   |   2
    2   |   2
```

In the above table structure, you have the two main object tables, and one relational table, called UserPolls. This will scale pretty well, for any number of polls you want.
Then, if you want to know which polls were taken by a given user, you can do:

`SELECT poll_id FROM UserPolls WHERE user_id = 1`

Or if you want the opposite. Polls not taken by a given user:

`SELECT id FROM Polls WHERE Polls.id NOT IN (SELECT poll_id FROM UserPolls WHERE user_id = 1)`

*Note: this is not tested code, but you get the general idea on how to go about designing and normalizing your tables.*